# WMI: sort by connection order with WMI

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, wmi

Currently I'm using `WMI` to detect cameras devices connected to my Windows PC:

```
public static List<CameraDevice> GetAllConnectedCameras()
{
    var cameras = new List<CameraDevice>();
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')"))
    {
        foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
        {
            cameras.Add(new CameraDevice()
            {
                Name = device["Caption"].ToString(),
                Status = device["Status"].ToString(),
                DeviceId = device["DeviceId"].ToString()
            });
        }
    }

    return cameras;
}

public class CameraDevice
{
    public int OpenCvId { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

With output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Microsoft LifeCam Cinema",
    "DeviceId": "USB\\VID_045E&PID_0812&MI_00\\7&2E33922C&0&0000",
    "Status": "OK"
  },
  {
    "Name": "FLIR USB Video",
    "DeviceId": "USB\\VID_09CB&PID_1007&MI_00\\6&1E15415F&0&0000",
    "Status": "OK"
  }
]
```

However, if I disconnect and reconnect one of these two devices, or If I restart the computer, their connection order changes. I know this because I use these methods in conjunction with `OpenCvSharp`, which allows you to connect to a camera only by its kind of index (and it doesn't provide an enumeration for this). `OpenCvSharp` orders each camera by its connection sequence to the system, I'd like to obtain the same with WMI.

So, if `Microsoft LifeCam Cinema` is connected **before** the other, it should have a lower index and viceversa.

Is it possibile? Is there some properies I could use to **sort by connection order**?

Thanks!

Comment: i dont think there's a way to get which device connected first, but why do you need the connection order? maybe we can bypass your main problem?

Comment: It is because OpenCv orders its webcam enumeration by connection order and I wanted to reproduce the same behavior.